# How to access the line variable of a `clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException` instance?

Tags: exception, clojure, introspection

Trying to access the `line` variable of a `clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException` instance fails, yet when I inspect [the code](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/ddc65a96fdb1163b3c8cb112d565f06c4137b575/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java#L6285) for the exception I can clearly see that the line variable exists. For example:

```
user=> (try
  #_=>   (load-string "(+ 2 3)\n(- 3 4)\n())")
  #_=>   (catch clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException er
  #_=>     (. er line)))
IllegalArgumentException No matching field found: line for class clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException  clojure.lang.Reflector.getInstanceField (Reflector.java:271)
```

When I instead expect `3` to be the result.

Not accessing the `line` variable, and simply returning the exception actually shows me the line!

```
user=> (try
  #_=>   (load-string "(+ 2 3)\n(- 3 4)\n())")
  #_=>   (catch clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException er
  #_=>     er))
#<CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unmatched delimiter: ), compiling:(null:3)>
```

What's going on?

**edit:** Using on clojure 1.4.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line member was not added until 1.5.0 in [this commit](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/commit/89245c68e867640e8dd4bd948b4ac2a283935702) which closed [CLJ-788](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-788).

You'll have to update to **Clojure 1.5.0** to access this member.